Transversality Characterization for Vector Spaces
Let be $V$ and $W$ vector space, $Z\leq W$ and $T:V\to W$ a lineal transformation.
I want to proof that, $T\pitchfork Z$ iff $\forall~h:[0,1]\to GL(W)$, $\forall~w:[0,1]\to W$, differentiable functions such $h(0)=\text{Id}_{W}$ and $w(0)=0$, the functions $\forall~t\in [0,1],$
$$T_{t}:V\to W~;~v\mapsto h(t)(T(v))+w(t)$$
satisfy
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\text{dim}(T^{-1}_{t}(Z))=\text{dim}(T^{-1}(Z))$$

My attempt:
Since $T[V]+Z=W$, using Grassman formula:
$$\text{dim}(T_{t}^{-1}[Z])=n-\text{dim}(T_{t}^{-1}[~T[V]~])+\text{dim}(K)$$
here $K=T_{t}^{-1}[Z\cap T[V]]$ and $\text{dim}(V)=n$. I suposse I have to use Transversality Theorem and the obtain that for
for almost everything $t\in [0,1]$,   $T_{t}\pitchfork Z$. But I don't know how to work with the functions $T_{t}$ and besides Transversality Theorem is for manifolds. Also, the sentence of the exercise says that $\text{dim}(T^{-1}_{t}(Z))=\text{dim}(T^{-1}(Z))$ for a $t$ enought closer to $0$. I interpreted that with the limit but I don't know if that's what it means.
Any help will be apreciate. Thanks.

First, vector (sub)spaces are manifolds. Second, shouldn't $K$ be $K_t$?

$K$ is just a name, but yes i suppose is more appropriate $K_{t}$. And yes, I know that vector spaces can be gifted with the structure of differentiable manifolds, but transversality of manifolds is not exactly the same concept.

Au contraire, it is a more general notion which specializes to the case of vector spaces.
